# Problemas con la api Comunication

Tags: javascript, html, api

Estaba realizando un curso de html , cuando llego a la api comunication sale error en mi chrome , internet explore no sale error pero la barra no carga correctamente.Lo tengo subido a mi host para las pruebas.

```
function leer(){
    var url="video_prueba.mp4";
    
    var solicitud= new XMLHttpRequest();
    solicitud.addEventListener("loadstart",comienza_barra,false);
    solicitud.addEventListener("progress",estado_barra,false);


    solicitud.addEventListener("load",mostrar,false);
    solicitud.open("GET",url,true);
    solicitud.send(null);

}

function comienza_barra(){
    zonadatos.innerHTML="<progress value='0' max='100'></progress>";
}

function estado_barra(e){
    var porcentaje=parseInt(e.loaded/e.total*100);
    var barraprogreso=zonadatos.querySelector("progress");
    barraprogreso.value=porcentaje;

    zonaprogreso.innerHTML=porcentaje+ " %";
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que intentas hacer y cuál es el mensaje de error completo que aparece en Chrome?

Comment: "Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLProgressElement': The provided double value is non-finite.
    at XMLHttpRequest.estado_barra"  , hace una peticion a  video.mp4 que esta en el host y la barra tiene que mostrar cuanto de % esta cargando @Triby

Comment: ¿Dónde defines la variable `barraprogreso` y qué tipo de elemento HTML es? Aparte, sería bueno que veas en consola los valores que estás manejando, por ejemplo: `console.log(e.loaded, e.total, porcentaje);` antes de asignar el valor.

Comment: zonadatos es un section donde va a cargar la barra , barraprogreso es la barra que indica cuanto % va cargando de mi peticion video_prueba.mp4

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que en algún momento e.total es 0, con lo que te da un NaN la división

Comment: Si lo acabo de revisar el e.total sale 0 , e.loaded si sale  numero